# Python show value in line chart

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had created a chart with values (LSMA5['Low']), I'm able to plot the chart, but I want to show the values at each point of the chart, how can I do that?

Here are the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.figure(figsize=(12.6,4.6))
plt.plot(stock_store['Close'], label='ABCsTock', alpha=0.35)

plt.plot(LSMA5['Low'], label='LSMA5', alpha=1, linewidth=1)

plt.title('ABCsTock')
plt.xlabel('Jan. 01,2018 - Jul. 30,2020')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Thanks with regards

JC

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're trying to do, here's a way to do that (with synthetic data):

```
x_arr = np.arange(10)
y_arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
plt.plot(x_arr, y_arr)

# zip joins x and y coordinates in pairs
for x,y in zip(x_arr,y_arr):

    label = "{:.2f}".format(y)

    plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y), # this is the point to label
                 textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                 xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                 ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks for the reply. Regarding x and y: 
x_arr = np.arange(10)
y_arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

For x is the date which I understand, but for y_arr=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10), I only have 1 column of data for Y, but here it seems have 3 values.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand the question correctly. Please include a sample of the data you're trying to plot, as well as the expected output (even as a drawing on a back of a napkin).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!